# LAME3.98 encoded music has foreign title

Tags: music, google-play-music

I copied a couple albums to my Note 2 that have LAME3.98 encoding and they show up with  maybe Chinese for the Album and song name, it does this on both the stock music and play music apps, the songs show up fine on my computer. Maybe this is an issue with how android reads LAME3.98 songs? How can I get them to show properly without converting my music? It also has ID3 tag v2.3

Comment: You should add a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I used the iTunes option to convert the ID3 tags to v2.2 and it fixed my issue.